# Sitecore 7 Content search .ToLower() method not supported, looking for alternatives

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I am working on sitecore 7.2 content search, I want to compare the document title with a string but In lowercase, When I use .ToLower() method in search clause, I get error that .ToLower() method is not supported, exact error is : 
`8648 11:19:34 ERROR Unsupported string method: ToLowerInvariant.
8648 11:19:34 ERROR    at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionParser.VisitStringMethod(MethodCallExpression methodCall)`

Is there any way to do case insensitive string comparison?

Comment: Are you using the default Sitecore Lucene configuration, and the default field analyzer for this field?  If so, that's the StandardAnalyzer, which automatically applies lowercase filtering.  [More information about Sitecore analyzers is here.](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Getting-to-Know-Sitecore/Posts/2013/07/Understanding-Analyzers-and-Sitecore-7.aspx)

Comment: yes I am using default Lucene configuration and default analyzer for all fields but that's giving error.

Answer (score 2):

you dont need to apply ToLower() - the search is per default using case insensitive search for text fields

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the lucene analyser type is

```
Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer
```

Sample index field configuration is

```
<field fieldName="subject" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="0.3f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
    <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
</field>
```